# Rails 5 ActionController::UrlGenerationError - missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am following a tutorial in [Agile Web Development with Rails 5](https://pragprog.com/book/rails5/agile-web-development-with-rails-5) but replacing the `Product` model with `Membership` so I can adopt it for a project I am working on.  I am coming from Django and am very new to the Rails way.

The error I am getting is with my `button_to` helper when trying to pass the `Membership Id` through the `line_item_path`. I have typed it verbatim except for the replacement of the model name.

I am not really sure how much code I should place here without adding too much.  If you need more, please ask.

**error** *The error says `missing required keys: [:id]` but I can't figure it out*

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership_id=>#<Membership id: 1, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

**rake route**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
      line_items GET    /line_items(.:format)           line_items#index
                 POST   /line_items(.:format)           line_items#create
   new_line_item GET    /line_items/new(.:format)       line_items#new
  edit_line_item GET    /line_items/:id/edit(.:format)  line_items#edit
       line_item GET    /line_items/:id(.:format)       line_items#show
                 PATCH  /line_items/:id(.:format)       line_items#update
                 PUT    /line_items/:id(.:format)       line_items#update
                 DELETE /line_items/:id(.:format)       line_items#destroy
           carts GET    /carts(.:format)                carts#index
                 POST   /carts(.:format)                carts#create
        new_cart GET    /carts/new(.:format)            carts#new
       edit_cart GET    /carts/:id/edit(.:format)       carts#edit
            cart GET    /carts/:id(.:format)            carts#show
                 PATCH  /carts/:id(.:format)            carts#update
                 PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)            carts#update
                 DELETE /carts/:id(.:format)            carts#destroy
contribute_index GET    /contribute(.:format)           contribute#index
                 POST   /contribute(.:format)           contribute#create
  new_contribute GET    /contribute/new(.:format)       contribute#new
 edit_contribute GET    /contribute/:id/edit(.:format)  contribute#edit
      contribute GET    /contribute/:id(.:format)       contribute#show
                 PATCH  /contribute/:id(.:format)       contribute#update
                 PUT    /contribute/:id(.:format)       contribute#update
                 DELETE /contribute/:id(.:format)       contribute#destroy
     memberships GET    /memberships(.:format)          memberships#index
                 POST   /memberships(.:format)          memberships#create
  new_membership GET    /memberships/new(.:format)      memberships#new
 edit_membership GET    /memberships/:id/edit(.:format) memberships#edit
      membership GET    /memberships/:id(.:format)      memberships#show
                 PATCH  /memberships/:id(.:format)      memberships#update
                 PUT    /memberships/:id(.:format)      memberships#update
                 DELETE /memberships/:id(.:format)      memberships#destroy
```

**views/contribute/index.html.rb**

```
...
<tbody>
  <%= cache @memberships do %>
    <% @memberships.each do |membership| %>
        <%= cache membership do %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= image_tag(membership.image_url, class: 'list_image') %></td>
          <td><%= membership.title %></td>
          <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
          <td>
            <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
            <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership_id: membership) %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
...
```

**controllers/concerns/current_cart.rb**

```
module CurrentCart

  private

  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

**controllers/line_item_controller**

```
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...
  def create
    membership = Membership.find(params[:membership_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(membership)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  ...
```

**controllers/cart_controller**

```
def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**models/cart.rb**

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**models/line_item.rb**

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :membership
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

**log from 7-25-2017**

```
Started POST "/line_items/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 01:14:53 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/line_items/1"):

actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 01:14:58 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership=>:membership_id}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership: :membership_id) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338848706380'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338848706380'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338848706380'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338848706380'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 01:15:34 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership_id=>#<Membership id: 1, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership_id: membership) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338828018020'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338828018020'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338828018020'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338828018020'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 07:16:24 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership_id=>#<Membership id: 1, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership_id: membership) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338848879380'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338848879380'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338848879380'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338848879380'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:19:16 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :line_item=>{:membership_id=>#<Membership id: 1, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(line_item: {membership_id: membership}) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338828990200'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338828990200'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338828990200'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338828990200'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:19:29 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership_id=>#<Membership id: 1, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership_id: membership) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338837000860'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338837000860'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338837000860'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338837000860'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:21:02 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership_id=>2}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership_id: 2) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338847529580'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338847529580'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338847529580'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338847529580'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:30:29 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership_id=>#<Membership id: 1, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership_id: membership) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338849783140'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338849783140'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338849783140'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338849783140'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:47:51 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership_id=>#<Membership id: 1, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership_id: membership) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338795119760'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338795119760'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338795119760'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338795119760'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:48:05 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items", :membership_id=>#<Membership id: 1, title: "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap", description: "<p>\n      <em>Powerful, Effective, and Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    22:           <td><%= sanitize(membership.description) %></td>
    23:           <td>
    24:             <%= number_to_currency(membership.price) %> <br>
    25:             <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership_id: membership) %>
    26:           </td>
    27:         </tr>
    28:         <% end %>

app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:25:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338835755640'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:18:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338835755640'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338835755640'
app/views/contribute/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_contribute_index_html_erb___1918836646394839137_70338835755640'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:55:17 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  [1m[36mMembership Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "memberships".* FROM "memberships" ORDER BY "memberships"."title" ASC[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (8.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 27.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/line_items/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:55:18 -0700
Processing by LineItemsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mLineItem Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find LineItem with 'id'=1):

app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:71:in `set_line_item'
Started GET "/line_items/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:56:44 -0700
Processing by LineItemsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mLineItem Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find LineItem with 'id'=1):

app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:71:in `set_line_item'
Started GET "/line_items/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:57:00 -0700
Processing by LineItemsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mLineItem Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find LineItem with 'id'=1):

app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:71:in `set_line_item'
Started GET "/contribute" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:57:11 -0700
Processing by ContributeController#index as HTML
  Rendering contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("memberships"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "memberships"[0m
  Rendered contribute/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 18.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/line_items/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 10:57:13 -0700
Processing by LineItemsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  [1m[36mLineItem Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find LineItem with 'id'=3):

app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:71:in `set_line_item'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"line_items",
>   :membership_id=>#\n      Powerful, Effective, and
>   Efficient F...", image_url: "dcbang.jpg", price: 0.45e2, created_at:
>   "2017-08-25 05:50:58", updated_at: "2017-08-25 05:50:58">}, missing
>   required keys: [:id]

You have two mistakes in the code.

Firstly,

```
line_item_path(membership_id: membership)
```

should be

```
line_item_path(membership)
```

And

You should use `link_to` instead of `button_to`, as `button_to` generates a **form** which will send a `POST` request by default which will error out in your case as your route expects a `GET`

```
<%= link_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(membership) %>
```

Comment: That git rid of that error, now I am getting `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LineItemsController#show Couldn't find LineItem with 'id'=3` - here's the code in my line_items_controller `def set_line_item @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id]) end`
`def line_item_params params.require(:line_item).permit(:membership_id, :cart_id) end`

Comment: @StudioRooster Can you update the question with the logs?

Comment: @StudioRooster It means there is no `LineItem` with *id =3*. Isn't it strange that you are trying to pass a *membership object* to look for a `Lineitem`? Make sure you pass the correct instance for the `LineItem`

Comment: I added the log from just today since I just started working.  And per your last comment, I have three objects in the database right now with id's 1, 2 and 3

Comment: @StudioRooster Do you have those objects in memberships table? Its unclear whether you want to look for a LineItem or Membership.

Comment: They are in the membership table.  I assumed that when following this tutorial that when I added the membership item to cart, it would pass the membership item into the lineitem table - maybe I am missing some key points here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I must have been working too hard because although I reviewed the code several times, I missed a spelling error.  Where I had `line_item_path(membership_id: membership)` I should have pluralized the LineItem Path as `line_items_path(membership_id: membership)` and `button_to` was correct since I was posting a new membership to the cart model. Definitely a learning experience.